# Fujifilm compressed RAW on macOS Ventura

Tags: fujifilm, macos

On macOS Ventura the compressed RAW format of the Fujifilm cameras (e.g. FujiFilm X-Pro 2) is seemingly still not supported.

1. In finder I can't see a thumbnail preview of the image.
2. The previewer (space bar) doesn't show the image (just the file type icon).
3. I can't edit the image in the real Preview app.

This only works for the uncompressed variant of the file format.

How can I add support compressed Fujifilm RAW files support to macOS Ventura so all of the three things mentioned above work.

Comment: See [Fuji RAW files & Ventura](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254360761?answerId=258165448022#258165448022) for some other people asking a similar question.  But I doubt that you can do anything yourself, and instead will have to wait on Apple.  Also see [Digital camera RAW formats supported by iOS 16, iPadOS 16, and macOS Ventura](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213267) and pay attention to the footnotes.